# Count of active records between date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, like:

First Table **(Users)**

```
Id    Name   Active
-------------------
1     X      1
2     Y      1
3     Z      1
4     X1     0
```

and the second table **(Records)**

```
Id    UserId    Date
---------------------------
001   1         2015/09/19
002   1         2015/09/20
003   1         2015/09/09
004   2         2015/09/15
005   4         2015/09/20
```

From these tables I need to get the following result - if I filter on `Date between 2015/09/21 and 2015/09/10 and Active=1` the result that I need like this

```
UserId       Name     Count
---------------------------
3            Z        0
2            Y        1
1            X        2
```

`Count` is the number of records in table `Records` in the selected range date and active=1

Comment: Are you using MySQL, SQL Server, or both?  This question has both tags.  Can you share the query you've tried, even if not working?

Comment: @Dan Guzman I'm using sql-server but I think the select statement are much similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first you have to join both the tables based on `id` .

Please do note that this is `left join` because we want `0 count` values.

Apply the active criteria after this as `where` clause and before `group by`.
Use the `SUM` aggregate function with `case` logic as we want `0 count` values.

```
select 
  u.id as [UserId], 
  u.Name as [Name],  
  sum(case when r.[Date] between '2015/09/10' and '2015/09/21' then 1 else 0 end) as [count]

from [users] u left join [records] r
  on u.Id =r.UserId 
where u.active=1
group by u.Id, u.Name
```

demo sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9c3a/12
demo output:

```
UserId  Name    count
1   X   2
2   Y   1
3   Z   0
```